# NPM fallback dependency URL

Tags: npm, dependencies

I have a npm dependency in my project which is pointing to a private git repo. Unfortunately the git repo link does not work in my local but it works fine when we do a jenkins build since that git repo link only allows certain whitelisted ip's (i.e. jenkins ip address).

I have looked into apache proxypass and verdaccio but I am not sure if that is the right approach for this

```
dependencies": {
    "api-module": "git+https://example/repo-name.git",
},
```

Locally, I want `https://example/repo-name.git` to route to `https://differentUrl/repo-name.git` when I do npm install but don't want to update package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to setup a host entry and provide an alias to that